# How can I find a message in a link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was recently creating a bot.

Right now I am trying to find out if someone could help me with my `-verify (mc uuid)` command. It would check a URL to see if their `uuid` is in the fetched object. So, if I did `-verify (uuid)` and it is found, it would give me a role.

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');

module.exports = {
    name: `verify`,
    async execute(message, args) {
        fetch("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=29083d9d-58cf-4a71-95be-d24f31c018b7&name=Metanoia")
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(({ guild }) => {
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808886143416270899');
        const uuid = args[0];
        if(uuid) {
            //
        }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"it would give me a role"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive an object from the API URL. Its `guild` property has a `members` array. The array contains objects with `uuid`s. If you want to find one with the provided `uuid`, you can use the [`.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) that returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

In your testing function you can test if the object's `uuid` is the same as the member provided `uuid`:

```js
const foundElement = array.find((el) => el.uuid === uuid);
```

In your code it looks like this:

````js
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');

module.exports = {
  name: `verify`,
  async execute(message, args) {
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('808886143416270899');
    const uuid = args[0];

    if (!uuid) {
      return message.channel.send(`uuid is not provided`);
    }

    try {
      const result = await fetch('https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=29083d9d-58cf-4a71-95be-d24f31c018b7&name=Metanoia');
      const { guild } = await result.json();
      const member = guild.members.find((member) => member.uuid === uuid);

      if (!member) {
        return message.channel.send(`No member found with uuid ${uuid}`);
      }

      // you can do anything with the found member
      message.channel.send('```' + JSON.stringify(member, null, 2) + '```');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error');
    }
  }
}
````

If your `execute` method is already an async function, you can use async/await to fetch the results. I used that in my code above.

[image]